# Use a checkbox to display or hide an input with Angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I need to display or hide an input with a checkbox, the structure is like this :

```
<input type="checkbox"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Something"
       value="{{ctrl.value}}" ng-if="checkbox checked">
```

How to simply do it in angular ?

Comment: I highly recommend you take an Angular course as this is one of the very first things you will learn, it will help you a lot in the long run. [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: Yes i did it with a simple ng-if, thanks .

Comment: The question uses AngularJS code and is tagged as AngularJS; the answer accepted is Angular 2+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the first things you will learn when exploring Angular, and going through the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/docs), so I highly recommend researching this.

Regardless, to make this work you need some values in the ts file, that you can bind to your html file, using ngModel, will probably work best for you.

TS file

```
inputHidden = false; // This determines whether the text input is rendered or not
ctrl: { // This follows the convention you've outlined, with ctrl.
   value: any
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="inputHidden">
<input type="text" placeholder="Something" [(ngModel)]="ctrl.value" *ngIf="inputHidden">
```

Comment: Thank you, i found it by myself, i asked because every answers i found before seemed pretty complicated for doing this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="ctrl.checked"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="Something" value="{{ctrl.value}}" ng-if="ctrl.checked">
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.